# SWI Prolog Database

Tags: prolog

is there a way I can query a SWI Prolog database to check if it doesn't contain an element?

I have tried using "not" but doesn't seem to work with this version of Prolog.

Comment: If you have defined something like `st(1).` and when you execute your program you type a query `st(45).` you would get `false` as an answer. That would mean that the database you've created doesn't contain that element. Is that what you want?

Comment: Perhaps you can be explicit about what you've tried and in what way it "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: SWI-Prolog's 7.1.0 documentation [urges developers](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=not/1) to use "\+" rather than "not" for new code.  See [bottom of page here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=control).  However "not" should still be available for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you're looking for [clause](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/2)/2. A dummy session sample

```
1 ?- [user].
|: a(1).
|: a(2).
|: a(X) :- b(X).
|: b(3).
|: b(4).
% user://1 compiled 0.03 sec, 6 clauses
true.

2 ?- clause(a(X),Body).
X = 1,
Body = true ;
X = 2,
Body = true ;
Body = b(X).

3 ?- clause(b(X),Body).
X = 3,
Body = true ;
X = 4,
Body = true.

4 ?- clause(c(X),Body).
false.
```

you can see that c/1 is not defined...

Anyway, SWi-Prolog database is a complex beast, and it offers [much more](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=examineprog) control about its contents.